# configuration of Eclipse (C++ version) for running SQLite?

Tags: eclipse, c++, sqlite

I need to run C++ code via eclipse which has SQlite. I can run it via terminal with typing g++ test.cpp -lsqlite3 . but how can I run it via Eclipse? how should pur the command "-lsqlite3" in its configuration? thanks

this is the begging of the code

```
#include <sqlite3.h> #include <stdlib.h> #include <string.h> // g++ test.cpp -lsqlite3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Eclipse FAQ](http://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/User/FAQ) on adding libraries:

**Adding C/C++ External Libraries**

```
How do I add an external library to my C++ project?  

Go to Your Project's Properties by right clicking on project's name and selecting   
properties. Click on "C/C++ Build". Under Tool Settings Tab, click on Directories.   
Click on The Add Button and Select FileSystem. Select the folder with C/C++ libraries.  
Apply and then Ok. The new library is included.  

The option commented before didn't work when I tried it. I solve it including the  
external library I want to add (libwsock32.a in my case) in Project->Properties->Tool   
Settings Tab->C++ Linker->Miscellaneous.  

14:26, 18 December 2007 (EST): Neither of these worked for me under Linux. I had to open  
up the project's properties and go to "C/C++ Build" -> "Settings" and then hit the  
"Libraries" item under "GCC C++ Linker" heading in the list on the right. Then, I  
entered the libraries as I would in the command line ("pthread" for libpthread, etc...).  
(Dustin Oprea)
```